# NH 3.0 GA Linq Group By not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

Is LINQ `group by` still not supported in NH 3.0 GA or I'm doing something wrong ? 
My LINQ is :

```
var q = from p in session.Query<Product>() 
        group p by p.Category into g 
        select new { 
                     Category = g.Key, 
                     TotalValue = g.Sum(p => p.UnitsInStock * p.Price) 
                   };
```

Witch is converted to the following SQL :

```
     select category1_.Id as col_0_0_, 
             cast(sum(product0_.UnitsInStock*product0_.Price) as DOUBLE PRECISION) as col_1_0_, 
             category1_.Id as Id0_, 
             category1_.Name as Name0_ 
     from [Product] product0_ 
             left outer join [Category] category1_ on product0_.Category_id=category1_.Id 
     group by category1_.Id
```

Because category1_.Name isn't in the group by clause this generates an  SqlException.

Is this a known bug ? Is there a workaround ? 
This LINQ works well in EF 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate's `group by` is not smart enough to add all the properties of an entity when grouping by it.

An alternative would be to use the Id only in the select list and then use `session.Load` in Linq-to-objects to project the Category entity.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first information I found on why group by wasn't working.

Comment: I found the answer here : http://blog.patearl.net/2010/12/nhibernate-30-linq.html : NH3 Linq is not finished, still in beta ...